# Force override/extension of method with body

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations, overriding

I'm looking for a way to easily and often force user to override method that has already a body, call super and possibly add some code. Simple example would be externalization process, where careless user extending class forgets to override externalization and that leads to unnecessary hassle later on, when someone else tries to externalize that object, finds out it is not implemented and has to go through understanding of someone else's code just to write externalization.

I was not able to find acceptable solution that does not include making most of the classes abstract (which disrupts their use).

Is it possible do something like that for example with annotations?

```
class Bar{
    @SuggestOverride
    @Override
    public void foo(){}
}
```

This way could IDE shout at user extending Bar whenever foo() is not overriden. (at least warning) (IDE Eclipse/Netbeans)

I'm not very familiar with annotations, and I'm not sure if it is worth it investigating too deep in just to find out it is not possible at all. I would be very grateful if anyone suggested solution.

With kind regards,
Vojtěch Kaiser

EDIT: I was probably not clear enough, here is example code

```
abstract class Foo{
    public abstract void method();
}

//instantiable
class Bar extends Foo{
    @Override
    public void method() {
        //some code
    }
}

//instantiable
class Socks extends Bar{
    //doesn't know about 'method'
}
```

Comment: Why not create an Abstract Class with an abstract method?

Comment: As I mentioned, nearly every class in the inheritance chain is class that can be instantiated an used, which would be impossible with changing all classes to abstract (with exception of leaves of course)

Comment: Use unit tests to assure that classes behave as intended.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose definitely approach I would consider as last option (writing general unit test that will scourge all classes with reflection will take some work, but it might work), thank you for suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe an abstract class with a base method that contains an abstract body is an option:

```
abstract class Bar {

    public final void foo() {
        // add the base code for your method here
        // ...
        this.additionalWork();
    }

    // part that has to be overwritten
    public abstract void additionalWork();

}
```